# Woocommerce Separate Product Loops for Each Category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On the main shop page (archive-product.php) on my Woocommerce shop, I want to be able to display all the products but separate them by categories. So I would need to be able to create a loop for each product category.

For a visual reference, this is what I'm trying to achieve: [for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ4C2.jpg)

Each gray block represents a new category and will loop through the products in that category.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you also need pagination or not?

Comment: No pagination needed as the shop page will display all products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as you mentioned in the comment, if you don't need any pagination, to list all products leading by their category you can first loop through the categories using [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) function and get whatever information you need on each iteration ( e.g: category name ), and then create one custom query per category and show the query's products, something like this will get you what you're trying to do:

```
<?php
foreach( get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat' ) ) as $category ) :
    $products_loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'product',

        'showposts' => -1,

        'tax_query' => array_merge( array(
            'relation'  => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'terms'    => array( $category->term_id ),
                'field'   => 'term_id'
            )
        ), WC()->query->get_tax_query() ),

        'meta_query' => array_merge( array(

            // You can optionally add extra meta queries here

        ), WC()->query->get_meta_query() )
    ) );

?>
    <h2 class="category-title"><?php echo $category->name; ?></h2>

    <?php
    while ( $products_loop->have_posts() ) {
        $products_loop->the_post();
        /**
         * woocommerce_shop_loop hook.
         *
         * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );
        wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on your page template. It will get result for  Woocommerce Separate Product Loops for Each Category.

```html
$taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
  $orderby      = 'name';  
  $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
  $title        = '';  
  $empty        = 0;

  $args = array(
         'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
         'orderby'      => $orderby,
         'show_count'   => $show_count,
         'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
         'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
         'title_li'     => $title,
         'hide_empty'   => $empty
  );
 $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
 foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
    if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
        $category_id = $cat->term_id;       
        echo '<br /><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a>';
  
  
 //get product
  $args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'product', 
 'product_cat' => $cat->name,
  'posts_per_page' => $count,
  'paged'          => $paged,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
    $query->the_post();
        ?>
  <span class="title"><h2>  <?php the_title(); ?> </h2></span>
        <?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

 }
 }
```